# Read Image EXIF Data in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to read EXIF data of an image. More importantly, I need to find orientation information about an image that is loading from a remote service for instance https://storage.googleapis.com/my-app-images/xxx.jpg

I tried to use EXIF-JS library but couldn't figure out why was it not working in angular 6.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how the library is not working with angular? How do you use it? Show us some code please.

Comment: @Zak  
I'm using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif-js  After installing via npm, inside component, I'm importing the library like this:
import * as EXIF from "../Path-to-node-module"

Then when the image URL is available, I would do something like this:
 EXIF.getData('https://storage.googleapis.com/my-app-images/xxx.jpg', function() {
        var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
        var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
    });

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/

Comment: The function EXIF.getData need the image content in base64, not the image url. You need to read the image and convert it to string first, than pass it to EXIF.getData

Answer (score 3):

In my Angular 6 app I added

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>
```

to my index.html

Inside the component i needed exif I import it on top -> `const EXIF = require('exif-js');`

and then use the standard function:

```
getExif(result) {
    console.log(result);
    EXIF.getData(result, function() {
        const make = EXIF.getTag(this, 'Make');
        const model = EXIF.getTag(this, 'Model');
        const orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, 'Orientation');
        const makeAndModel = document.getElementById('makeAndModel');
        console.log(make, model, orientation);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a snippet for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exifjs-example
Image is provided using base64 string because as far as I know, Stackblitz doesn't support assets in Angular projects. Also, notice that `exif-js` is included with `script` tag in `index.html` using CDN. In your project you could use local file if you want to.

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/hiri-web-images/6fd04d605ad44d8f836d79eb7ab79723.jpg

Help me with this image. Note a base 64 encoded.

Comment: @JamesJ Download your image and encode it as base64.

Answer (score -1):

Hi @Ivan just got worked in angular 7 application. Below is small change in your answer -

Instead of including script tag in index.html I have used

```
npm install exif-js --save
```

and in module file of component use it as a provider.

Comment: How did you add it as a provider? When I add `EXIF` there (with the corresponding import), I get an error that `EXIFStatic` is not assignable to type `Provider`.